# Preconfiguring ssh password for server installer

Tags: system-installation, ssh, password

I am trying to install Ubuntu Server on a device on which the available HDMI port broke down, so I can't connect a display whatsoever. I read in the docs ([here](https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/install/general)) that it was possible to connect to the installer over SSH. I managed to boot into the Installer on my device, and found the IP address with the corresponding open ssh port. The problem is, that I don't know the password to use and I can't read it from the screen either as is intended if I understood it correctly. Some online resources suggested it might be `ubuntu` but that was not the case.

Is there a way to set the key/password beforehand or modify it?

I already found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1231639/password-for-ssh-server-in-installation-environment) question about pretty much the same problem, yet it did not contain an answer I can use.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using the "live-server" installer (*subiquity*) then the default settings will create a user named `installer` with a random password.  The `installer` user can be used to access the installer TUI by SSH.

Depending on the version of *subiquity* the randomly generated password is printed to the screen or is available under the Help menu.

The `installer` user is created by `cloud-init` when the installer boots.  By changing the `cloud-init` configuration it is possible to set the password or to add SSH Key(s) for the `installer` user to something known.  There are a couple of ways to configure `cloud-init`.

**Use Autoinstall**

I have been able to set the `installer` password by using an `autoinstall` file.  The file has content like the following to set a password and set an SSH key.

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
...
# set password to r00tme
chpasswd:
    expire: false
    list:
        - installer:$6$.c38i4RIqZeF4RtR$hRu2RFep/.6DziHLnRqGOEImb15JT2i.K/F9ojBkK/79zqY30Ll2/xx6QClQfdelLe.ZjpeVYfE8xBBcyLspa/
ssh_authorized_keys:
    - ssh-rsa FILLINYOUROWNKEYHERE
```

**Modify the ISO**

I have not done this, but you could try modifying the ISO.  The `installer` user setup is configured in the [`/etc/cloud.cfg` file](https://git.launchpad.net/livecd-rootfs/tree/live-build/ubuntu-server/includes.chroot.ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg?id=d11c71a6869a65036d3cefb5a67e33500073c62a#n78).  You could modify this file to define a password or SSH key.

**See Also**

- [set ssh ssh-password on autoinstall](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1321795/set-ssh-ssh-password-on-autoinstall/1322129#1322129)
- [Current source that seems to set the password](https://github.com/canonical/subiquity/blob/90a2bd6f7a754964f1f35028ebf97aa305b29de5/subiquity/server/server.py#L538)

Answer (score 1):

One can indeed make a modified server installer disk. The below steps are based on the [Ubuntu LiveCD customization instructions](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization%5D) and this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1389300). Alternatively you can start from [this bash script](https://github.com/berndpfrommer/ubuntu_server_installer_mod) and modify it to your needs.

1. Download `ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso` and mount it:

   ```
   mkdir ub && mount ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso ub
   ```
2. Mount the squash file system with the relevant installer info and copy it:

   ```
   mkdir sqfs && mount ub/casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.squashfs sqfs
   find sqfs -xdev -print0 | cpio -pa0V nsqfs
   ```
3. Edit the `cloud.cfg` file with your favorite editor, e.g `vi nsqfs/sqfs/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg` to
   have a passwd, and also add your ssh key here:

   ```
   default_user:
     name: installer
     lock_passwd: false
     ... don't other stuff ...
     # password r00tme
     passwd: $6$.c38i4RIqZeF4RtR$hRu2RFep/.6DziHLnRqGOEImb15JT2i.K/F9ojBkK/79zqY30Ll2/xx6QClQfdelLe.ZjpeVYfE8xBBcyLspa/
     ssh_authorized_keys:
       - ssh-rsa HERE_YOUR_SSH_KEY
   ```
4. Make a copy of the (read-only) mounted installer disk (`ub`) into `ub_mod`:

   ```
   mkdir ub_mod && cd ub && tar cf - . | (cd ../ub_mod; tar xfp -) && cd ..
   ```
5. Squash the modified files:

   ```
   cd nsqfs
   mksquashfs sqfs ../ub_mod/casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.squash
   cd ..
   ```
6. Update the size file:

   ```
   printf $(du -sx --block-size=1 nsqfs/sqfs | cut -f1) > ub_mod/casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.size
   ```
7. Change the signature (not sure that's needed), replacing the `local-user` key with your own (list your keys with `gpg --list-secret-keys`):

   ```
   rm ub_mod/casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.squashfs.gpg
   gpg --local-user 2661D59A01F3022FAFB75644F440B26DF14188A2 --output ub_mod/casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.squashfs.gpg --detach-sign ub_mod/casper/ubuntu-server-minimal.ubuntu-server.installer.squashfs
   ```
8. Recompute the md5 checksum:

   ```
   cd ub_mod
   rm md5sum.txt
   find -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | grep -v isolinux/boot.cat | tee md5sum.txt
   cd ..
   ```
9. extract the MBR and the EFI partition from the original ubuntu installer disk. You need to
   adjust the `count` and `skip` fields below according to the output you get from the `fdisk` command

   ```
   fdisk -l ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso
   dd bs=1 count=446 if=ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso of=mbr.img
   dd bs=512 count=10068 skip=4156048 if=ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso of=EFI.img
   ```
10. use `xorriso` to find the flags necessary to create the new boot disk:

```
xorriso -indev ~ubuntu-22.04.3-live-server-amd64.iso -report_el_torito cmd
```

Then modify them to reference the mbr and EFI. My `xorisso` line ended up looking like this (copied into bash file to edit/run):

```
#!/bin/bash
xorriso -outdev hacked_installer.iso -map ub_mod / -- -volid 'Ubuntu-Server 22.04.3 LTS amd64' -volume_date uuid '2023081005062500' -boot_image grub grub2_mbr=mbr.img -boot_image any partition_table=on -boot_image any partition_cyl_align=off -boot_image any partition_offset=16 -boot_image any mbr_force_bootable=on -append_partition 2 28732ac11ff8d211ba4b00a0c93ec93b EFI.img -boot_image any appended_part_as=gpt -boot_image any iso_mbr_part_type=a2a0d0ebe5b9334487c068b6b72699c7 -boot_image any cat_path='/boot.catalog' -boot_image grub bin_path='/boot/grub/i386-pc/eltorito.img' -boot_image any platform_id=0x00 -boot_image any emul_type=no_emulation -boot_image any load_size=2048 -boot_image any boot_info_table=on -boot_image grub grub2_boot_info=on -boot_image any next -boot_image any efi_path='--interval:appended_partition_2_start_1039012s_size_10068d:all::' -boot_image any platform_id=0xef -boot_image any emul_type=no_emulation -boot_image any load_size=5154816
```

The only fields I had to touch are the references to `EFI.img` and `mbr.img`

If all went well you should now have a boot disk `hacked_installer.iso` into which you can log on using your ssh key