# non-live iso for ubuntu server 22.04

Tags: 22.04

I can not use ubuntu 22.04 live server (ubuntu-22.04.2-live-server-amd64.iso) and I certainly need non-live one. How can I access it?

thank you

Comment: I don’t understand your question - the iso you mention at https://releases.ubuntu.com/jammy/ is the iso for installing Ubuntu server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420087/ubuntu-22-04-reinstallation-without-a-screen

Comment: The non-live Server installs used the *debian installer* which stopped being used many releases ago, and isn't available for *supported* releases of Ubuntu anymore, if that's what you're after.  The closest now is https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD for 23.04 not 22.04 (*though it talks about a replacement for how di was used; i'm a desktop user and thus don't monitor server that closely sorry*)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 22.04 reinstallation without a screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420087/ubuntu-22-04-reinstallation-without-a-screen)

Comment: @guiverc that was super useful for coming back to reproducible server installs.

Answer (score 0):

[Automated Server installation](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/automated-server-installation/16612)

> Since version 20.04, the server installer supports automated installation mode (autoinstallation for short). You might also know this feature as unattended, hands-off, or preseeded installation.

> Autoinstallation lets you answer all those configuration questions ahead of time with an autoinstall config, and lets the installation process run without any interaction.

Already answered?

[Ubuntu 22.04 reinstallation without a screen](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1420087/ubuntu-22-04-reinstallation-without-a-screen)

> The Ubuntu Server installer for 20.04 and later supports a new mode of operation: automated installation, autoinstallation for short.

Debian answer but it could apply to Ubuntu as well:
[How to Install and Set Up Headless Linux](https://www.baeldung.com/linux/install-headless-linux)