# SSH into Ubuntu 22.04 server installer

Tags: server, system-installation, ssh, 22.04

I am trying to install ubuntu 22.04 remotely through SSH. It seems that the SSH server is running out-of-the-box but I do not know the username and password. Is there a default username and password combination or do I still need psychical access to the machine to set it up?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems as though, at least using an unmodified 22.04 install image, that you need physical access to the box.  This is because by default, the new Ubuntu installer (subiquity) sets the SSH password for the "installer" user to a randomly-generated string.  You can view it from the Help menu in the installer.

If you want to set the password to a known value, you have to fuss with `autoinstall` or (possibly) modify the `/etc/cloud.cfg` file on the ISO (which would involve rebuilding the ISO image).  See Andrew Lowther's answer to this question: [Preconfiguring ssh password for server installer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1389280/preconfiguring-ssh-password-for-server-installer)

It seems…less than ideal…for headless installations, but that's the way it currently is.